# h1 and img in html5 not applying css

Tags: html, css, image

I am working on a simple website for studying purposes.  My goal is to keep all the code in a HTML5 format and use the new semantic tags as much as possible.  In the code below the font and size changes that I make are not being reflected to the website, so no changes in the css is applied to the html page.  I am not sure what is going on:
Here is the html and css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dasmoto's Arts & Crafts</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <span>Dasmoto's Arts & Crafts</span>
        <img src="./resources/images/pattern.jpeg" alt="">
    </header>
</body>
</html>

header {
    position: relative;
}

header span {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: khaki;
}

header img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: There's no `<link>` or `<style>` element. Why should the CSS do anything? It sounds like it is just sitting in a file near your HTML but not connected to it.

Comment: You have to add a ```<style> add your CSS here </style>``` inside your head tag. Move all the CSS inside here.

Comment: If you're concerned about semantics, then don't neglect heading elements (like `h1`) and don't use content `img` elements for backgrounds (which can be applied using CSS).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I have been looking at this for a couple of days and have made so many different modifications, just forgot the simple one.